# How to select and change value in dropdown list <select> via CSS

Tags: html, css, select, replace

Thanks in advance for the help.

Given the HTML below, how might one use CSS to find the "Please Select..." value in the dropdown and **replace** it with "Choose a State"?

```
<span class="label"><label for="state">STATE</label></span>

<select id="state" name="state" class="inputbox" size="1">
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
    <option value="AL" class="USA">AL</option>
    <!--truncated for brevity -->
    <option value="WI" class="USA">WI</option>
</select>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: You could make the entire dropdown out of CSS, as shown in http://koen.kivits.com/articles/pure-css-menu/ . Just style the `onclick-menu-content` so that it's positioned over the `onclick-menu`, and has an item (an `li`, presumably without a button) that has the text you want ("Choose a State")

Comment: Are you changing on an event? What is the use case. Javascript is probably your answer. CSS cannot handle events or manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done using CSS.  (CSS cannot query your document for content strings and replace)

Use **JavaScript** or a popular JS library designed for DOM manipulation like jQuery

**Example** using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

```js
$("#state option").text(function(idx, txt) {
  if(txt==="Please Select...") return "Choose a State";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="label"><label for="state">STATE</label></span>
<select id="state" name="state" class="inputbox" size="1">
  <option value="">Please Select...</option>
  <option value="AL" class="USA">AL</option>

  (truncated for brevity) 

  <option value="WI" class="USA">WI</option>
</select>
```